# Change a single product quantity using state (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So ,I wanted to change this one product object in the UI with a button click, and reduce the quantity of the product. But the quantity amount did not change .What is the best move in situations like that.

```
let product={ a:1,b:2,c:3};
```

Lets say changing the value.

```
b:5;
```

Comment: `const [products, setProducts] = React.useState({ a: 1, b: 2, c:3 });`
then you can change the products object like that: `setProducts({ ...products, b: 5 });`

Comment: This should be the answer, instead of a comment.

Answer (score 0):

please check this sample code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([
    { name: 'Product 1', qty: 1, price: 10 },
    { name: 'Product 2', qty: 1, price: 20 },
  ]);

  const [totalAmt, setTotalAmt] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const total = products.reduce((s, i) => s += i.price * i.qty, 0);
    setTotalAmt(total);
  }, [products]);

  const incrQty = (index) => {
    setProducts((v) => {
    const a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v)); // FOR AVOIDING MUTATING DATA, BECAUSE IN STRICT MODE THIS SETSTATE CALLBACK WILL TRIGGER TWICE
      a[index].qty += 1;      
      return [...a];
    });
  };

  const decrQty = (index) => {
    setProducts((v) => {
    const a = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(v));
      a[index].qty -= 1;      
      return [...a];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      Total Amount: Rs.{totalAmt}
      <ul>
        {products.map((e, k) => (
          <li key={k}>
            {e.name}, qty={e.qty}, subtotal {e.qty * e.price},
            <button onClick={e => incrQty(k)}>Incr Qty</button>
            {
              (e.qty > 1)?<button onClick={e => decrQty(k)}>Decr Qty</button>:null
            }
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```